# How to get selected element text from jlist with image icon?

Tags: hive, jtextfield, jlist, selecteditem

[Error Image Using Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMYB8.png) I'm trying to display the selected element text in a jtextfield from jlist. The list contains database data and image, where getting selected value from list following error throws.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: hive.test.ImgsNText cannot be cast to java.lang.String

My code

```
String index = String.valueOf(jList1.getSelectedIndex());
jTextField1.setText(index);
String s = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
jTextField2.setText(s);
```

Getting database data and displaying in jlist-code

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "arunachalam", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "show databases";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String s1 = rs.getString(1);
            dm.addElement(new ImgsNText(s1, new ImageIcon("images/hive_db.png")));
        }
        jList1.setCellRenderer(new Renderer());
        jList1.setModel(dm);
        if(jList1.isSelectedIndex(0))
        {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Exception");
    }
```

Suggest me how to get the text alone from jlist and displaying it in jtextfield.

Comment: You have to create a `ListCellRenderer` of Label that contain the image and string both in your list

Comment: Can you provide your Exception log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a `ListCellRenderer` that is used to show the image and text both in `List`. and then call a `ListSelectionListener` on list that capture event of click on list selection.Then get the selected item and set the text of selected item in Text field.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ListExample implements ListSelectionListener {

  JList list;
  DefaultListModel listModel;
  JTextField txtField;
  Connection connection;
  PreparedStatement pst;
  ResultSet rs;

  public ListExample() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LIST");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container con = frame.getContentPane();

    ListRenderar rendrar = new ListRenderar();
    list = new JList();
    txtField = new JTextField(10);

    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganesh", "root",
          "admina");
      pst = connection.prepareStatement("show databases");
      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        String text = rs.getString(1);
        listModel.addElement(new ImgNText(text, new ImageIcon("/images/help.gif")));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.setModel(listModel);

    list.setCellRenderer(rendrar);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);

    con.add(list);
    con.add(txtField);

    con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
  }

  public class ListRenderar extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
                                                  boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

      ImgNText imgNtext = (ImgNText) value;
      ImageIcon icon = imgNtext.getImage();
      String name = imgNtext.getText();

      setIcon(icon);
      setText(name);

      return this;
    }
  }

  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    ImgNText obj = (ImgNText) list.getSelectedValue();
    txtField.setText(obj.getText());
  }

  public class ImgNText {

    ImageIcon image;
    String text;

    public ImgNText(String text, ImageIcon image) {
      this.image = image;
      this.text = text;
    }

    public ImageIcon getImage() {
      return image;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return text;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ListExample();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ganesh, but you were used predefined data. My process it to fetch and display database data in list with image icon. Once it is done, then i need to display the selected item from jlist to jtextfield. Is there any other way to solve the issue. I tried with object, same error follows.

Comment: @Arunachalam You can see the updated code in which i fetch the data from DB

Comment: In windows os String s = (ImgNText)jList1.getSelectedValue(); jTextField1.setText(s1); works fine using netbeans. Doing the same in ubuntu throws the error of cannot cast text with image. Do you have any idea abt this?. Mysql database works good, i need to do in apache hive.

Comment: i,m using jdk 8 oracle. Not open jdk. I will accept the answer if the problem is solved don't worry about that

Comment: Actually my friend you cannot cast the ImgNText file into string  you have to copy the  object into reference then you have to call getter methods for text fetching

Comment: Yes ganesh, done with class files containing same getter and setter. but i didnt attached the code here. I done as you were posted, even though the problem is getting text from jlist element. It works fine in mysql, but it is not working in hive as database.

Comment: You check that your data is properly fetched.I am think you do like this first fetch the data after then create a `ImgNText` object then add it into `listModel` after that you add the `listModel` into  `list`.When you click item on  list , at `ListSelectionListener` you do like this `ImgNText obj = (ImgNText)list.getSelectedValue();` and then `txtField.setText(obj.getText());`...You do the same or  not ,After doing this there is less chance of Exception occur

Comment: I tried this step . Same error obj cannot be converted to string. I'm stuck in this. But anyway thanks for your assistance.

Comment: if you try this step you cannot get the error of obj cannot be converted to string, Here in code we are not typecast the Object into String

Comment: We typecast the Object into ImgNText not in String

Comment: I will post you with image in my question part. Wait Ganesh

Comment: See Error image using object in my question section. @Ganesh

Comment: Don't typecast like that ImgNText obj = ((ImgNText)list.getSelectedValue()); Use this only  ImgNText obj = (ImgNText)list.getSelectedValue();

Comment: Then, what should i do. Even i tried out removing cast.

Comment: You see there is lot of difference  in your code and in my suggestion use this ImgNText obj = (ImgNText)list.getSelectedValue(); no more extra  paranthesis that you use in your code

Comment: Give me time bro. I'm going to modify some changes in my code. Once resolved means i will intimate @ganesh

Comment: Thanks @ganesh for your assistance. It resolved my issue.